# Magento 1.9.1 Bug? Discount + Tax + Paypal Pro = incorrect total

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, discount, paypal-pro

I have a problem with a magento store 1.9.x

I configured tax for the products and i created a coupon code -30%.

When i proceed to Checkout with Paypal Pro, the imports for the products are incorrect.

**Example:**

**Product**: 100$ incl. tax
**discount40** %: -30$
**shipping**: 5$
**tax**: 12.62$
**TOTAL tax escl**. 62,38 
**TOTAL**: 75$

**the Review in Paypal PRo:**

**Total item**: 51,97$
**TAX**: 12,62$
**Shipping**: 5$
**TOTAL**: 69,59

The problem appears only when 
- The tax is actived & configured
- Customer use a Coupon Code
- The payment method is PayPal Pro.

If the customer use a different payment method or don't use a coupon code the problem does not occur.

I tested the problem on a clean installations (1.9.0.1 and 1.9.1) and with the same configurations, the problem appears.

It's a reported bug? how do I fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that discount is calculated AFTER taxation, when paypal tries to calculate it BEFORE.
I solved extending the Mage_Paypal_Model_Hostedpro_Request class and adding the hidden tax amount to the tax, resulting in

```
protected function _getOrderData(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
    {
        $request = array(
            'subtotal'      => $this->_formatPrice($order-getBaseSubtotal()),
            'tax'           => $this->_formatPrice($order->getBaseTaxAmount() + $order->getHiddenTaxAmount()),
            'shipping'      => $this->_formatPrice($order-getBaseShippingAmount()),
            'invoice'       => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'address_override' => 'true',
            'currency_code'    => $order->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
            'buyer_email'      => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'discount'         => $this->_formatPrice(
                $order->getBaseGiftCardsAmount()
                + abs($order->getBaseDiscountAmount())
                + $order->getBaseCustomerBalanceAmount()
            ),
        );
...
```

I'm planning to put everything in an extension if someone is not able to do it. Stay in touch because I could forget about it :D

**EDIT**
[Here it is!](https://github.com/fullbl/Magento-PaypalFix)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's the state on this? :)

Comment: As far I can see, nothing changed in paypal extension, but I don't know where I could contact them!

(thanks to Sabuj for pointing the missing +, I corrected it!)

Answer (score -1):

```
'tax'           => $this->_formatPrice($order->getBaseTaxAmount() $order->getHiddenTaxAmount()),
```

Is there will be `+` sign between `$order->getBaseTaxAmount()` and `$order->getHiddenTaxAmount()` ?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. The answer is yes. But please do not use the answer form to comment on other answers.